# get image from image.files with objectid

Tags: python, django, image, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a problem with mongoengine. I get an objectid of an image in image.files collection. How could I get the image in django, just like **image.files.objects(pk=objectid).first()**?
Is there any apis for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just query the `grid_id` and return the matching document like so:

```
class TestImage(Document):

    image = ImageField()

TestImage.drop_collection()

t = TestImage()
t.image1.put(open(TEST_IMAGE_PATH, 'rb'))
t.save()

test = TestImage.objects.first()
grid_id = test.image1.grid_id

self.assertEqual(1, TestImage.objects(image1=grid_id).count())
```